# Mounting inside mounted read-only volume

Tags: mount, fstab

I have mounted nfs volume in my `/etc/fstab` as

```
nfshost.com:/path/dir  /mount/point  nfs     rw,sync,hard,intr       0       0
```

I'd like to mount another nfs volume

```
nfshost.com:/completely/different/path  /mount/point/subdirectory  nfs     rw,sync,hard,intr       0       0
```

However, it doesn't seem to work, I get the error message

```
mount.nfs: mount point /mount/point/subdirectory does not exist
```

I also can't mount it manually with `sudo mount nfshost.com:/completely/different/path /mount/point/subdirectory`. Mounting it anywhere else, e.g. `sudo mount nfshost.com:/completely/different/path /tmp/test` works.

I suspect that the problems are that I neither have write access to the originally mounted `/path/dir`, nor does it have the subdirectory to which I'd mount the other volume. Creating the directory structure `/mount/point/subdirectory` locally, mounting first into `subdirectory` then into `mount/point` works, but then `mount/point` contains the mounted volume and I can't access `subdirectory`.

```
ls /mount/point/subdirectory
ls: cannot access '/mount/point/subdirectory': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to mount these volumes to achieve this directory structure?

Comment: have you tried using bind option ? Like this `sudo mount -o bind nfshost.com:/completely/different/path /mount/point/subdirectory`

Comment: @Rahul: `mount: mount point /mount/point/subdirectory does not exist`

Comment: you'll need  root accces on /mount/point, either local (if exported with access/root) or on nfshost.com to issue `mkdir /mount/point/subdirectory`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the directory first.

`mount` doesn't create a mount point if it doesn't exist.  That's why it's telling you `mount point /mount/point/subdirectory does not exist`

Try:

```
sudo mkdir /mount/point/subdirectory
sudo mount nfshost.com:/completely/different/path /mount/point/subdirectory
```

If you don't have write access to `/mount/point/` then you can't create a directory in it.  You'll have to mount the second directory somewhere else.

Comment: "Creating the directory structure /mount/point/subdirectory locally, mounting first into subdirectory then into mount/point works, but then mount/point contains the mounted volume and I can't access subdirectory."

Comment: yes, that's because you mounted the nfs share over the local directory, i.e. replaced it.  you need write access to `/mount/point/` **after** the nfs share has been mounted.

Comment: I have a feeling that I didn't completely replace it, as I can still `sudo umount /mount/point/subdirectory` successfully, I'm just unable to access it in any other way...

Comment: no, it didn't "completely replace it".  the directory and its contents aren't deleted, you just can't get at them easily while something else is mounted over the directory.